# How should we tag questions about space?

Tags: discussion

Current tags about space or similiar topics:

[space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) [spaceship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceship) [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) [planetoids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetoids) [astronomy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy) [meteorology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meteorology)

Some of these belong in their own tags, while it may be argued that others are too localised, or synonymous with other tags, and should be merged into other tags. Respond with a proposal of which tags should be kept (it could be *all* of them and I might just be overzealous here), and which ones should be merged into other tags.

Comment: Should we have a tag "tags" on meta for questions like this?

Answer (score 10):

First off, remember that tags should be useful for **grouping questions based on subject matter.** Someone who is an expert in a particular area should be able to follow a particular tag and be notified of questions to which they are likely to be able to provide good answers, or be notified of questions that they are likely to  be interested in. *Too much segregation between tags goes against that goal.* A tag should also provide meaningful information **when used on its own** on a question.

In that venue, I feel **planets** and **planetoids** are similar enough that separating them doesn't make much sense. Someone who is familiar with one is likely to be familiar with the other.

**space** when referring to the part of the universe outside of a planet's atmosphere appears overly broad. It can probably be replaced with some other tag where it is used. Maybe **astronomy** would be useful on questions that perhaps otherwise would be tagged just **space**. I do think that we should have a tag **space-travel** that deals with questions pertaining to travel through the universe. A related tag could be **travel** or **terrestrial-travel** for travelling on or near a planet's surface (for example: on foot, by horseback, dog sled or airplane).

**astronomy** and **meteorology** seem like good tags to me, assuming that the subjects themselves are to be considered on topic.

Answer (score 2):

I would say keep all of them for the next week and then we can review tags/burninate some. But definitely wait and see how they develop between now and then.