# Can I get some help burning fantasy-based?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

[We have consensus on burning](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1830/so-lets-talk-about-burning-the-fantasy-based-tag) [fantasy-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-based)!

Now we need to actually go through and remove it...

Except that there are 80 questions using it as I write, and that is a whole lot of work. The reason this is such a big task is that we don't just need to remove the tag, we also need to see if there is an appropriate tag to replace it with, for example [mythic-creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythic-creatures), [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design), [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic), [etc](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etc).

I intend to start going through the questions later today and editing their tags, but I would appreciate some help doing so :-)

Comment: I'll aid you in your noble quest my young squire! ;)

Comment: I've done 4-5 so far.

Comment: I've done 5 now.

Comment: I love you guys, down to 38 now :-) By which I mean, thank you to everyone who is helping.

Comment: Bloody hell, we *murdered* that thing! We also seriously screwed up the "active" tab.

Comment: Pffft, well, that is what happens when there is no mod tool to do it :-)

Comment: You slapped that "status-completed" tag too early on this: I just removed the last remaining "fantasy-based" tag. ;-)

Comment: @celtschk Ooh, someone added on the tag in a rollback after we finished destroying it. Thanks for removing it.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been completed!

I'd like to thank Dustin Jackson and Bowlturner for their help. I'd also like to stare in amazement at HDE 226868 and Serban Tanasa for the amazing speed at which they burned through the tags. Trying to remove a tag and finding that HDE had just snipped it from under me was happening far to frequently.

Thanks to anyone else who I might have missed in dealing with this.

Enjoy sorting by activity for the next day or so :P

Comment: Just saying, Serban sniped me waaaaay to often! :-)