# Hard Science not-so-hard: wiping out humanity

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, specific-question

The question

[How to wipe out humanity within a week?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20829/how-to-wipe-out-humanity-within-a-week)

is marked with a [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science). But, IMO neither the question, nor any of the answer really live up to the exigence. Or am I being too strict?

Note: this follows the previously discussed point

[A hard-science ultimatum](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2211/a-hard-science-ultimatum)

Comment: I see no mathematical equations. Thus, it is not hard-science.

Comment: bilbo_pingouin - I agree, and have downvoted some of the answers for this reason. @DaaaahWhoosh Equations are not needed for it to be [tag:hard-science]!

Comment: @HDE226868 From the wiki: "All answers to this question should be backed up by equations". And I like math.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh " . . . empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc." Those are examples, not requirements. I like math, too.

Comment: IMO, some questions aren't good fit for the hard science tag, or the tag is misused. Maybe we should take a tag editing day to put tags in order? The hard science tag but others as well.