# Do we need both [medicine] and [medical] tags?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

We currently have [medicine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine)

> For questions about treatment methods as well as substances used to heal wounds and cure diseases.

with 77 questions thus tagged. We also have [medical](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical)

> For questions about the diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of disease and injury.

with 26 questions thus tagged.

Do these two really warrant separate tags? Can they be merged into one? If so, which one should that be, and what should the tag wiki say? If they can't be merged into one, how should the difference be made clear to someone, perhaps a newcomer, asking a question so that they know which one to use?

Compare for example the discussion in [my answer to the old question *How should we tag questions about space?*](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34/29)

Answer (score 2):

We just need one.

Medicine is the sciene while medical relates the medecine.

The definitions are almost identical but I have a preference for the medical one.